# What is the unit of measurement in Jmeter latency report

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to do load test on my rest api development with Jmeter. Everything is good but I'm confused with the measurement of the result.

when it says latency = 44 is it in miliseconds?

[image: I'm confused with the report]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it’s milliseconds.

See:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Aggregate_Report

« Times are in milliseconds »

See also:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html

Answer (score 2):

Yes latency is measured in milliseconds in jmeter

Answer (score 1):

Mostly units in the jmeter is in milliseconds (ms) and I am sure latency is also measured in jmeter in milliseconds.